# What Are Other Ways to Do 2-Column Layouts?

Tags: css

I've been stuck with this approach for a 2-column site for quite a while now

1. wrap elements in a "wrapper" div
2. float main div to the left
3. float sidebar to left
4. apply clearfix on the wrapper div

the problem I am often having is that whenever a non-floated element in the main div is alongside a floated one, I always have to do clears or clearfixes.

do you have any other approaches for 2-column layouts. by the way, I use the said approach in [my blog](http://ygamretuta.com):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a grid: http://www.1kbgrid.com/

It's more than just a 2-column layout, but I like the idea of it being flexible. For instance, it's really handy when you have some fancy layouts on the front page and fall back to your default 2-column on all the subpages. Saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

For the `#wrapper` use `overflow:auto` instead `clear`.

Read more at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: I'm using this clearfix by Perishable Press, which, if I recall it right, recommends the approach over the overflow approach: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/

Comment: @Ygam I still find `overflow` more useful. In any case, I checked your blog, and I didn't see exactly what you describe. Can you create a demo of the problem you face at http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ ?

Comment: no need. look at the header and content divs and ul for each post from the front-page source, I alwys apply the clearfix class to make the non-floated container wrap around the floated child elements.

Comment: if you remove the clearfix:after, and you add `overflow:auto` for `#header` and `.post` you get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I too used your method until i found [Yahoos YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/), check it out!